# remove value from array when multiple exist just remove one

Tags: php, arrays, reduce

I have an array like so:

```
[a, b, c, d, e]
```

I have a value i want to remove from the array in this case `a`

now the array should look like this:

```
[b, c, d, e]
```

this is easy i can just do:

```
$del_var = 'a';
if (($key = array_search($del_val, $array)) !== false) {
    unset($messages[$key]);
}
```

but i the case i have an array with contains the search value `a` twice or more i just want to reduce the count of the value by one. like so:

```
[a, a, a, b, c, d]
```

should give me:

```
[a, a, b, c, d]
```

how would i go about this?

Comment: If you were consistent with the array name ($array or $messages) your code should work as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably get one instance of a key using `array_keys`:

```
if (($key = array_search($del_var, $array)) !== false) {
    $keys = array_keys($array, $del_var);
    // get the first key;
    if (!empty($keys)) {
        unset($messages[$keys[0]]);
    }
}
```

Assuming you're searching for `a`, `array_keys` should yield all the key indices of `a` inside `$array`. Then just get the first one (or depending how many you want), you can unset them using the occurences.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use a for loop and if you encounter the value `a` you [unset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) the value and stop the loop so the unset will be done only once.

```
$array = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
$del_var = 'a';
for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
    if ($array[$i] === $del_var) {
        unset($array[$i]);
        break;
    }
}

print_r($array);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/cXAT4)

That will result in:

```
Array
(
    [1] => a
    [2] => a
    [3] => b
    [4] => c
    [5] => d
    [6] => e
)
```

Answer (score 0):

array_keys() returns all the keys that match the value of the search (= 2nd parameter). count() counts the results of array_keys(). If count is higher than 1 unset the first element with that value.

```
$array = array('a', 'd', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'b', 'd', 'e');

$result = array_keys($array, 'b');
if(count($result) > 1){
  unset($array[$result[0]]);
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => d
    [3] => c
    [4] => b
    [5] => b
    [6] => d
    [7] => e
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a foreach loop, like this:

```
$array = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'e'];
$del_var = 'a';

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
  if($value == $del_var){
    unset($array[$key]);
    break;
  }
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($array);
echo "</pre>";
```